# Connecting rows in a list if they exist?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list that I am reading in with Python:

```
with open('african_countries.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

The file african_countries.txt is in the format below:

```
Algeria       Algeria
Algeria       Libya
Algeria       Mali
Algeria       Mauritania
Algeria       Morocco
Algeria       Niger
--------------------------
Angola        Angola
Angola        DR Congo
Angola        Namibia
Angola        Zambia
--------------------------
```

The first column in the file lists every country in Africa in alphabetical order. The second column lists the countries with direct borders to the country in the first row in alphabetical order. I have the file saved into a list where I can loop through each line. I have some regex that can identify direct borders but I am trying to figure out how to loop through when given two countries (without a direct border) and see how many borders need to be crossed in order to connect them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, post your attempts

Comment: Hello, @Tyler would be appreciated If you can give us some tested data and expected output. two thing I've mentioned are much more  important that your 5-6 lined explanations.

Comment: @Tyler Looks like Graph Theory problem, regex can not solve that.

Comment: @terces907 Sample input would be Algeria and Egypt. The output would be 2. Algeria to Libya and Libya to Egypt. I thought I might be able to get it solved by making a series of regex, how would you go about creating a graph in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph theory problem and you'l find the solution for it in [here](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/).

The first thing you need to do is build something like this:

```
    graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
             'B': ['C', 'D'],
             'C': ['D'],
             'D': ['C'],
             'E': ['F'],
             'F': ['C']}
```

, but with countries instead of letters (example 'Algeria':[Libya,Mali,...]). To achieve this you'll have to read you entire file and for each country obtain a key and it's values (basically the information inside each of those blocks you've shown).

From this point you can use the function on the link I gave above:

```
def find_shortest_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return None
    shortest = None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_shortest_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath:
                if not shortest or len(newpath) < len(shortest):
                    shortest = newpath
    return shortest
```

,which can be used in the following manner:

```
>>> find_shortest_path(graph, 'A', 'D')
['A', 'C', 'D']
>>>
```

EDIT: Fast solution to transform a file into a graph dictionary.

```
    fid = open('out.txt','r')
    lines = fid.readlines()

    key = ''
    group = []
    graph = {}
    for l in lines:
        if l[0]=='-':
            graph[key]=group
            key = ''
            group = []
        else:
            sp = l.split()
            key = sp[0]
            group.append(sp[1])

    print(graph)
```

with result:

```
    {'Angola': ['Angola', 'DR', 'Namibia', 'Zambia'], 'Algeria': ['Algeria', 'Libya', 'Mali', 'Mauritania', 'Morocco', 'Niger']}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is there a good way to construct the graph from the file I will read in?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Don't forget to accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: This is perfect thank you for the quick update. The only thing I am trying to figure out is having two word country names being in the same index of a list instead of multiple indexes for the multiple words in a country name?

Comment: The split function is using space as default separator. Knowing this you can create use another separator for fields instead of space, for example: l.split(';'). If you want to maintain your current format you'll have to build exceptions to the split or find some kind of reading rule for different elements. Let's say you have a list with all name for countries. "South" is not on that list, so it has to be a part of a name that is like "South Africa".